# What is the best practice to add domain based routing in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm working on a multitenant, multidomain Laravel project and of course the base of the software is the same for all users, but I have several users who asking me very specific things and don't want to build these features into the main codebase.

I separated the models, controllers, and migrations to namespaces like this:

```
app/Models/ClientSpecific/{ClientName}/{ModelName}
app/Http/Controllers/ClientSpecific/{ClientName}/{ModelName}Controller
database/migrations/client-specific/{ClientName}/{MigrationFile}
```

Going along this logic I want to add routes and I want to store it in separate files too:

```
routes/client-specific/{domainname.com}/api.php
routes/client-specific/{domainname.com}/web.php
routes/client-specific/{anotherdomain.com}/api.php
routes/client-specific/{anotherdomain.com}/web.php
routes/client-specific/{thirddomain.com}/api.php
```

How can load these route files only that domain what is called and only there? Is there any best practice to add domain based routing in Laravel? Or just add a domain check to the `RouteServiceProvider.php` based on `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store your domains in the `.env` file. That's will allow you to configure them in different environments.

```
APP_CLIENT_DOMAIN=client.com
APP_ADMIN_DOMAIN=admin.com
APP_DEVELOPER_DOMAIN=developer.com
```

Then, you can define different RouteServiceProviders for each domain, where each service provider will provide `api.php` and `web.php` routes for each domain.

Example:

This will be your BaseRouteServiceProvider:

```
abstract public function getDomain();

protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace(
                $this->namespace."\".Str::toCamelCase($this->getDomain()))
            ->group(base_path('routes/'.$this->getDomain().'/web.php'));
    }

protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->namespace(
                $this->namespace."\".Str::toCamelCase($this->getDomain()))
            ->group(base_path('routes/'.$this->getDomain().'/api.php'));
    }
```

Then you can define `FirstDomainServiceProvider`, `SecondDomainServiceProvider`, and more. In most cases, they will look like:

```
public function getDomain() {
    returt env('APP_CLIENT_DOMAIN')
}
```

Comment: The problem is there is more than 100 domains and I don't want to store it in the `.env` file, because the domains belongs to tenants, and managed in database.

Comment: For 100 domains this is really not the best way, in this case just use config and single RouteServiceProvider. Just call `mapApiRoutes()` and `napWebRoutes()` with `$domain` argument for each domain using loop.

Answer (score 0):

I created this solution, but maybe there is a better way. If you found it, please post it.

Thanks!

I changed the code in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` to this:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        // load client sepcific routes
        $host = request()->getHost();

        if (isset($host)) {
            try {
                Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/client-specific/'.$host.'/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/client-specific/'.$host.'/web.php'));
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    });
}
```